# Rewrite Sentences Ending with a preposition

Tags: prepositions, syntactic-analysis, prepositional-phrases

How can I rewrite this to where it doesn't end with a preposition?

*Background to the first example:*

We developers try to figure out what platforms websites use. Examples of platforms are Joomla, Drupal, Wordpress, and others.

Example 1:

> "Built With" is a more modern tool to determine what websites are
>   built **with.**

or perhaps this is a better example:

> Do you want to contribute to some publications on Medium.com? Super
>   Meditor is the right website **to go to.**

Answer (score -1):

You could say, rather clumsily, *"Build With" is a more modern tool, to determine with what websites are built.* Though I think you mean - *to determine with what websites should be built*; or more concisely put - *to determine the building blocks of websites*.

Equally, the simple answer to your second sentence is:*Super Meditor is the right website to which to go.* But it would be more succinct to say *Super Meditor is the website you need*

Comment: [Obligatory invocation of Winston Churchill](http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/quotes/w/winstonchu122535.html).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The OP asked how the sentences could be written without an ending preposition, and I have given examples which are grammatical; i.e I have answered the question as posed. However as you say they are not idiomatic. And that is why I have suggested more concise ways of saying the same thing. I don't see where we disagree.

Comment: (*Not my downvote as yet.) I don't equate 'ungrammatical' with 'unacceptable' (and I'd mark down someone using ' "Build With" is a more modern tool, to determine with what websites are built.' in an essay, or avoid purchasing a product described thus. *Someone apparently agrees with me.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I entirely agree with you. I would not accept such sentences. But how do you propose answering the question?

Comment: (b) It is, if acceptable at all as a reasonable question (asking for a rewrite), of ELL standard. But (a) it is asking for an inferior alternative, doubtless because the rule of thumb 'Never finish a sentence with a preposition' is being treated as more binding than Orwell's Sixth. // I have answered it in the same way I answered the question 'What is the best way to keep goldfish?' we once had. (Though the question on the acceptability of Addisonian terminations has been dealt with adequately here before.)

Comment: Eg, in @Araucaria's answer [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/170680/by-when-you-want-it-completed-vs-when-you-want-it-completed-by/172594#172594).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I still find ending prepositions untidy, a bit like my wife does the leaving of dirty socks on the bathroom floor.

Comment: [ODO blog](http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2011/11/grammar-myths-prepositions/) has a well-written corrective by Catherine Soanes on a prescriptive approach to preposition stranding.